# SwiftUI - How to have different value for Text according to a List

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

  let disciplines = ["Potato", "Tomato", "Onion"]

  var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            List(disciplines, id: \.self) { discipline in
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: DetailView(discipline: discipline)) {
                        Text(discipline)
                    }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle (Text("The App Title"), displayMode: .inline)
        }
    }
}



struct DetailView: View {
  let discipline: String
  var body: some View {
    Text(discipline)
  }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Right now for example, when I tap "Potato" in the List, the Text in the View will show "Potato".
But I want to have a different Text for each one of the Listed, not the same word.

How can I do that with SwiftUI?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an `ingredient` object and have two fields. One for the `name` and one for `description`

```
struct Ingredient: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var description: String
}
```

with this you would have to modify your `disciplines` to the following to take `ingredient` objects rather than strings

```
    let disciplines = [Ingredient(name: "Potato", description: "Yummy potato"),
                       Ingredient(name: "Tomato", description: "Yummy Tomato"),
                       Ingredient(name: "Onion", description: "Yummy Onion")]
```

and your view would change slightly to use the `name` and `description` fields from the `ingredient` object

```
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            List(disciplines) { discipline in
                NavigationLink(
                destination: DetailView(discipline: discipline.description)) {
                    Text(discipline.name)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle (Text("The App Title"), displayMode: .inline)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.

Comment: how can i add a default value, right now when the app is run at first, there is nothing in the detail view, how can I set something to be there when app starts? @sfung3

Comment: Can you explain a little further? You can't get to `DetailView` unless there are elements inside `disciplines` due to the `NavigationLink` @newGuy12

Comment: What I mean is that the code works well, but when you open the app there is nothing in the description side it is empty, until you tap something from the side table and get the description of what you tapped. So my question is, how to make it that when the app is opened to have something in the description?(even when user still didn't tap anything). @sfung3 thank you!

Comment: Is this for iPadOS?

Comment: it is catalyst thing, for iPadOS and macOS, using the same code. but was i clear or i still didnt explain myself very well? @sfung3

Comment: I've never worked on catalyst but here is a shot at it. Initialize `discipline` like this `var discipline = "hello world"`. Let me know if that works. If not can you update your question so I can give a better response. Currently I'm not sure how to test it since when I launch it on iPadOS, I can only get `DetailView` to show up when I choose something on the list. Thanks!

Comment: exactly that is what i mean, and no this didn't work. to update this post here? or to post a new one? thanks @sfung3

Comment: Either is fine, I'll check it out when you post it. interested in learning more about catalyst :)

Answer (score 0):

In my example below I've used the [MVVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel) concept to separate the View and it's logic. Next, the ViewModel contains two arrays/dictionaries:

1 . `disciplinesIds` holds unique ids to identify the disciplines
2 . `disciplines` holds the items to show itself, mapped to the ids

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct discipline {
    let name: String
    let content: String
}

final class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var disciplinesIds: [UUID] = []
    @Published var disciplines: [UUID : discipline] = [:]

    init() {
        for item: String in ["Potato", "Tomato", "Onion"] {
            let id = UUID()

            self.disciplinesIds.append(id)
            self.disciplines[id] = discipline(name: item, content: item + "_content")
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ContentViewModel

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            List(self.viewModel.disciplinesIds, id: \.self) { discipline in
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(discipline: self.viewModel.disciplines[discipline]!.content)) {
                    Text(self.viewModel.disciplines[discipline]!.name)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle (Text("The App Title"), displayMode: .inline)
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    let discipline: String

    var body: some View {
        Text(discipline)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(viewModel: .init())
    }
}
```

In your View, iterate through the list of ids in sake of performance (see this [article](https://troz.net/post/2019/swiftui-data-flow/)) instead of using the dictionary itself. You could even pass the `discipline` object to the view `DetailView`.